# how to get Latitude and Longitude of the given Name of the City or Address (java code)?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I want to get latitude and longitude from a city name in java project(eclipse) with GoogleMaps.
I tried with this code but I find multiple errors. I think because it is for Android.
I wonder if you can help me??

```java
public boolean getLatitudeAndLongitudeFromGoogleMapForAddress(String searchedAddress){

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(IPlant.iPlantActivity);
    List<Address> address;
    try 
    {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(searchedAddress,5);
        if (address == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "############Address not correct #########");
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);

        Log.d(TAG, "Address Latitude : "+ location.getLatitude();+ "Address Longitude : "+ location.getLongitude());
        return true;

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "MY_ERROR : ############Address Not Found");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged both google-maps and openstreetmap? Those are two different geocoders.  What errors do you get?

Comment: it asks me to define Geocoder, TAG, Adress .. i think i must to import some library .. but i don't know which library exactly

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is indeed for Android as it's using Android's [Geocoder class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder).

If you're trying to geocode addresses server-side in a web application, then you should use the [client libraries for web services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library) instead. The Java client can be found [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) and it provides the following code example for Geocoding API:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
    .apiKey("AIza...")
    .build();
GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
    "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043").await();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(results[0].addressComponents));
```

Note that you'll need a valid API key; I recommend you go through Google's [get started guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#overview).

Hope this helps you.